# vue-model in Vue.2.x

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-model

Example on above code is not working in my environment:

vue: ^2.2.1,

vue-model": 0.0.3,

```
    Vue.models.register('customer', {
        baseRoute: '/customers'
    });
```

After registering customer model by above example,
I supposed to able to refer customer object,

```
    customer.$.update()
```

but error returns,

> http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef  'customer' is not defined
>         /Users/murotanimari/my-project/src/components/Scene1.vue:19:1
>         customer.$.update()
>          ^

I assume that registration to vue model fails...
Does somebody know about the reason of this failure?

Comment: Try to use "this.customer"? BTW, this is a rarely used module, so u'd better ask this question in the "issue" list of its github repo.

Comment: Where are you calling customer.$.update() ? Normally when things are registered on the Vue instance you have to called this.$customer, or this.$models.customer, or something along those lines. Can you provide the rest of your code and how you are using this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this lib doesn't support vue2. You can try [vue-resouce](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource). It doesn't support model like operation, but really convenient to use.